# Rendered image is different to viewport

Tags: 3d-view

Okay to start off, I am FRESHLY new to blender so please bare with me. I only know the most basic stuff right now and currently learning... My issue is once I've rendered my final image, is it different to what I actually want and what I am viewing. The angle is slightly off: first picture is what I want it to come out looking like, second is what my final render is.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Hi Angel. Good work. The camera and the viewport have unique focal lengths. Set them to the same value. Does that answer your question?

OR

check to see if you have a keyframe on your camera that is repositioning your angle during render, but you haven't snapped to it in your animation timeline yet.

OR

You are in camera view, and you zoomed in or out while you didn't have the "camera to view" lock on. So you have distorted your viewport. I don't know how to reset this, but maybe try normalizing your zoom while you're in camera view.

Comment: Thank you, it was the first one you sent they was both different vales !